# Liferay 6.2 spring mvc portlet to apply filter to @ResourceMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, filter, liferay, xss, lifecycle

My Application is on Liferay 6.2 with spring mvc portlets.
I have filter for cross site scripting(XSS) for action and render mapping.

```
@RenderMapping , @RequestMapping and @ActionMapping
<filter>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class><pkg>.MyActionFilter</filter-class>
        **<lifecycle>RENDER_PHASE</lifecycle>
        <lifecycle>ACTION_PHASE</lifecycle>**
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <portlet-name>*</portlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But I am using `@ResourceMapping` for ajax call. where I am using `HttpServletRequest` to get the parameter value

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "ajaxOperation")
    public void inboundOperationsAdd(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
            throws Exception
    {

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil
                .getHttpServletRequest(resourceRequest);
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest= PortalUtil
                .getOriginalServletRequest(httpServletRequest);
```

and getting the parameter value from httprequest

```
String parameterValue = httpRequest.getParameter("paraName");
```

Now I want to introduce same cross site scripting(XSS) filter for @ResourceMapping.
I tried `<lifecycle>RESOURCE_PHASE</lifecycle>` but it is not working.

Please guide me how to do it.

***Updated on 26th Aug***
the filter working for `@RenderMapping , @RequestMapping and @ActionMapping`

from `portlet.xml`

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>FERenderActionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>sg.gov.frontier.filter.FERenderActionFilter</filter-class>
        <lifecycle>RENDER_PHASE</lifecycle>
        <lifecycle>ACTION_PHASE</lifecycle>
    </filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>FERenderActionFilter</filter-name>
        <portlet-name>*</portlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**And the filter**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.filter.ActionFilter;
import javax.portlet.filter.FilterChain;
import javax.portlet.filter.FilterConfig;
import javax.portlet.filter.RenderFilter;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;

public class FERenderActionFilter implements RenderFilter, ActionFilter {

    private static Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(FERenderActionFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
        throws PortletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

        chain.doFilter(new FERenderRequestWrapper(request), response);

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

        chain.doFilter(new FEActionRequestWrapper(request), response);
    }

}
```

**and the Wrapper 1**

```
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.filter.ActionRequestWrapper;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

import sg.gov.frontier.common.filter.FEParameterCleanup;

public class FEActionRequestWrapper extends ActionRequestWrapper {

    public FEActionRequestWrapper(ActionRequest request) {

        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {

        String value = super.getParameter(name);
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return FEParameterCleanup.cleanXSS(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {

        String[] values = super.getParameterValues(name);
        if (values == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int count = values.length;
        String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            encodedValues[i] = FEParameterCleanup.cleanXSS(values[i]);

        }
        return encodedValues;
    }

}
```

**and the Wrapper 2**

```
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.filter.RenderRequestWrapper;

import sg.gov.frontier.common.filter.FEParameterCleanup;

public class FERenderRequestWrapper extends RenderRequestWrapper {

    public FERenderRequestWrapper(RenderRequest request) {

        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {

        String value = super.getParameter(name);
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return FEParameterCleanup.cleanXSS(value);

    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {

        String[] values = super.getParameterValues(name);
        if (values == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int count = values.length;
        String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            encodedValues[i] = FEParameterCleanup.cleanXSS(values[i]);
        }
        return encodedValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: What hurdles are you facing in achieving the same?

Comment: Before this httpRequest.getParameter("paraName");, want to do the filter the value of "paraName". I tried javax.servlet.Filter with ResourceRequestWrapper Also ResourceFilter with ResourceRequestWrapper
but no success

Comment: Is it working fine for both action and render phases,and are you using a Hook or portlet for the same,and which file r u putting the filter mapping in??

Comment: both action and render filter are in my portlet and working fine, and I am trying ResourceFilter also inside same portlet.what not working.Can it work inside hook?

Comment: Could you provide implementation for your filter class to handle the action and render requests as the filters generally work on directly fetching servlet request?

Comment: Edited the question to add code

Comment: Hi Shivam, can you help me on this.

Comment: I saw your update,will update you soon

Comment: I was getting some 'Object intialization' errors while deploying the portlet due to some thing in the filter.Let me sort it up and get back!

Comment: is it resolved, else let me know, want me to share

Comment: Sorry mate,having a bad time with my machine.Thought to atleast inform you of the same.

Comment: Not sure,but you may try tagging some Liferay experts on this(if possible).Will surely get back once it's up and running.

Comment: Thanks for kind help and time.lets me know for any update.will try to get some liferay export

Comment: Btw,just to re confirm,did you also implement ResourceFilter interface for your FERenderActionFilter class,and what errors did u face in the same or did you get it sorted up?

Comment: yes,it works for me,can u give it a try?